# Ubuntu SSH issue

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH authentification with public key fails](https://superuser.com/questions/150532/ssh-authentification-with-public-key-fails)

Hi,
       I have the ubntun machine... under my /home/user/.ssh i have my id_rsa.pub key... i carefully copied that key and paste my key to respository Git account.

After that i try to connect from locat system to my git respository i got the following error

warning: Authentication failed.

Disconnected; no more authentication methods available (No further authentication methods available.).
.

I removed SSH in system and re-enable and did agin.. but no luck....

I have no idea what's happening with my SSH key ....can any one please tell me on this...

Note : i noticed in my home  /home/user/.ssh && /home/user/.ssh2